# Codeigniter on return type from model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

Hi I would like to ask help for a method in Codeigniter which is in the model,
so I just want my method to return the 'country_id' from 'countries' table in the database given its 'country_name', but I am unable to find the correct solution.
e.g Return the country_id

Here is the code which doesn't return the country_id value:

```
public function get_country_id($cname){
    $this->db->select('country_id');
    $this->db->where('country_name',$cname);
    $d=$this->db->get('countries');
    $d=$d->result();
    return $d->country_id;
}
```

Comment: What it returns actually right now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `$row` from query result. Then can return the `country_id` property of `$row`. Example:

```
public function get_country_id($cname){
    $this->db->select('country_id');
    $this->db->where('country_name',$cname);
    $d = $this->db->get('countries');
    $row = $d->row();
    return $row->country_id;
}
```